# Black background being affected by light source

Tags: lighting

I've encountered a weird problem lately, I have an object in the middle of the 3D space, and changed the background color of the viewport to black (#000) and use Cycles, the issue is that when rendered the background is not entirely black. I have a light source behind the camera to cast shadows on my object, but the light source also affects the background. This makes no sense to me as this is not how light behaves in real life, In real life light is only visible when it collides with something. But in the case of my project light from my light source is visible and affects my background color even though there is nothing for it to collide with. The only way I've found to fix this is to have no light source and use an emission shader on my object. With this technique the background of the object is pitch black but the emission shader also causes my object to have no shadows and to look differen than if it was illuminated by a light source. What I'm essentially asking of you guys is, do you know of any ways to have a pitch black background while still illuminating an object with a light source (the effect i'm going for is quite similar to how earth looks from space, earth is visible due to thte light from the sun but the vaccuum around earth is pitch black)?

[image: I've posted a picture to illustrate my issue, in the middle of the image you can see that it is lighter than on the edges, as if light was colliding with a plane or background even though my object is in empty space]

[image]

Comment: I've been trying for about 30 minutes to duplicate your result, but can't. Can you share your blend file?

Comment: If there were empty space around your object you're right, this behaviour makes no sense - but the space is not empty, see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You have a plane in your scene which has deactivated visibility in the *3D Viewport*, but is visible in *Render* (the camera symbol on the right).

[image: plane]

Comment: Tested it out with the plane deleted and you're right, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chronos138 You might consider accepting this answer: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)